# Fear of Information, which has been proven by statically data

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology, vocabulary, psychology, phobias

What is the **psychological terminology** for the fear of being presented with facts or shunning/deliberately ignoring facts?

Comment: I think this would better be answered on the **Cognitive Sciences** Stack Exchange.

Comment: What is "statically data"?

Comment: Probably "statistical."

Comment: *There are lies, damned lies, and statistics* was a phrase popularised by Mark Twain who attributed it to the British Prime Minister, Benjamin Disraeli (1804-1881). Various other people have been claimed as its originator, but it definitely wasn't Twain himself. I'm not sure how this addresses the question, except to point out that scepticism of statistics has never been restricted to the clinically phobic.

Answer (score 3):

**epistemophobia:** fear of knowledge
**veritaphobia:** fear of truth

Comment: Do you have any sources that show that these are "psychological terminology"?

Comment: Those of us who prefer not to mix Latin with Greek would use "alethophobia" for "fear of truth", and I'm amazed to see that it gets more hits on Google than "veritaphobia".  But I won't guess which term psychologists prefer.